# Excel, IF and COUNT duplicates

Tags: excel

So here it is,

Column A has duplicate and unique number values, Column B has duplicate and unique Strings (Names). I need to count the instances of unique number values in A matched to their name in B.

So it would be like =COUNTIF(B1:B100,"XYZ") "Then counts all **unique** number values in A1:A100 that "match" or have XYZ in column B.

- Col A - Col B
- ABC - 963
- ABC - 963
- FFF - 367
- FFF - 367
- FFF - 234
- XYZ - 678
- XYZ - 221
- XYZ - 334

What I need:

- ABC = 1  ( one unique instance where Col A and Col B (ABC,963) )
- XYZ = 3  ( three unique instances (XYZ,678 : XYZ,221 : XYZ,334
- FFF = 2  ( two unique instances ( FFF,367 and FFF, 234 )

So I need to sum up all the unique instances of Column A that only match the strings in column B.

Thanks in advance !, I'll keep searching in the meantime !

Comment: Sample data? Expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are looking to retrieve a count of the unique combinations of *number* and *name*. Perhaps something like the following.

[image: Unique Count]

The formula in E2 is,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$99<>"")/COUNTIFS(B$2:B$99, B$2:B$99&"", A$2:A$99, A$2:A$99&""))
```

The formula in E4 is,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$99=D4)/COUNTIFS(B$2:B$99, B$2:B$99&"", A$2:A$99, A$2:A$99&""))
```

Fill E4 down as necessary.

Comment: In your above table, I would need to figure out how to count Sue as having two different instances, so Sue is assigned the number 3 and 7 in the above table. I would need Excel to count that as she only has two corresponding numbers assigned. Sue = 2 unique numbers assigned (A5,A6 as 3 and A11 as 7).

Comment: I have one additional question, in the syntax of the formula can i change =SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$99=D4)....... can I change the D4 cell and have it reference only the string, such as =SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$99="ABC")  ?? THANK YOU

Comment: @DavidCzerepak  -Yes, you can hard-code text strings or numbers into the place currently occupied by D4. A fuller explanation of this process of *count unique* can be seen at [Count Unique with SUMPRODUCT() Breakdown](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2003-excel/count-unique-with-sumproduct-breakdown/1bc18979-4172-4537-993e-3897f74d6a5b).